# Jquery feedback plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I planned to implement `feedback` feature in my webApp. For this I Google and find `jquery plugin`.as per their documentation I included library in my html file and then I written the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //set up some minimal options for the feedback_me plugin
        fm_options = {
            bootstrap: false,
            name_placeholder: "Email Please",
            name_required: true,
            message_placeholder: "Go ahead, type your feedback here...",
            feedback_url: "",
            custom_params: {
                csrf: "",
                user_id: "mygmailUserName@gmail.com",
                feedback_type: "clean"
            }
        };       
        //init feedback_me plugin
        fm.init(fm_options);             
    });
```

plugin is coming pretty good just like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xxq7c10pys87qr/Plugin.png).

but the problem is after enter `email and message` If user click on `send` I am not getting any mail.

may be I miss some parameter values, I think I didn't mention the `csrf` attribute value may be because of that.I didn't understand what that attribute will do so I didn't mention.

For my webApp,their is no server it's just a static page.

can anyone help me.

Comment: feedback_url: "" how this message wil to to server?

Comment: @dev where can I find `url`,If I want to send message to `gmail` or `yahoo`. Also where am I need to mention my `login creadentials` because after user send message it should be come to my mail.

Comment: According to the code the `feedback_url` is required. So you need to create some sort of server side script to do this. _Description:  URL of your servlet/php etc ('name', 'message' and 'email' parameters will be send to your servlet/php etc...)_

Comment: in order to send an email, you need a mail server of any sort. static pages run on client machine and have no access to the client's machine therefore you cannot send email using javascript/jquery/or any of its plugins alone. what the feedback plugin does, is basically uses http post request to send information to a server page specified by the `feedback_url` attribute. similar to the `target` on a `<form>`. you need to create a page using any serverside language, host it somewhere and target it with the feedback_url. on that server page you need to write your code for sending an email

Answer (score 0):

Have you included a server handler for feebback i see `feedback_url: ""` then where will user data go to server?

So use a server script or a url like feedback.php etc and send email through it.

Create a url handler like SendFeedback.php then call this from

feedback_url: "SendFeedback.php"

SendFeedback may be like something

```
<?php
$to      = --get from ajax;
$subject =  --get from ajax';
$message =  --get from ajax;
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: this is not an answer, its a comment.